# Retrieving attributes for ManagedObjects

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Need to access Core Data records using Swift.

Ideally I want to call my class "Core Data" which returns the ManagedObject or false (no object exists). However currently when I want to retrieve the attributes on the ManagedObject I get compiler error **[NSManagedObject] does not have a member named 'valueForKey'**

I am aware of similar questions (e.g. [swift optional chaining with cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703794/swift-optional-chaining-with-cast)) but I have not been able to resolve this. Need help :)

For troubleshooting I am trying to access the attributes already in the class (will be done outside the class later). Code below. **Why am I getting the compiler error and how do I fix it?**

Thanks!

```
class CoreData{

    // Fetch existing data (from Core Data)
    func getData(entity: String) -> AnyObject {

        // Set delegate
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        // Get entity = a table (filter)
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:entity)

        // Create error variable
        var error: NSError?

        // Get record
        let fetchedResults =
        managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
        error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?

        if let results = fetchedResults {
            // Data retrieved
            var temp = results.valueForKey("gender") as String // <-- ERROR
            println(temp)
            return results
        } else {
            // Could not obtain data - log it
            println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSArray` has a `valueForKey` method, but Swift arrays don't.
You have the following options:

- Convert the Swift array to `NSArray`:

  ```
  var temp = (results as NSArray).valueForKey("gender") as! String
  ```
- Use `map()` on the Swift array and `valueForKey` for each object:

  ```
  var temp = map(results) { $0.valueForKey("gender") as! String }
  ```
- *(Recommended)* Let Xcode create the `NSManagedObject` subclass for your entity and use `map()` with the property accessors:

  ```
  var temp = map(results) { $0.gender }
  ```

(The above sample code is for the current Xcode 6.3/Swift 1.2, in earlier
version you have to use `as` instead of `as!`.)

Alternatively, you can create a fetch request with `.DictionaryResultType` to fetch only some selected attributes,
see [Fetching selected attribute in entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054621/fetching-selected-attribute-in-entities) for an example.

Comment: Martin R - you are the man! Reading up on the sub class option now - seems WAY better indeed - thanks for pointing it out!

Question from curiosity regarding Dictionary approach: If you request for multiple attribute and one (or several) does not exist - will the fetch fail all together - or bring the attributes which do exist?

**Thanks again - made my day - wishing you a great weekend!**

Comment: @PederWessel: You are welcome! – If `propertiesToFetch` contains any properties which are not actual properties of the entity then the fetch request will fail.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Enjoy the weekend