# Check for http response format

Tags: ios, swift

I am making http call and receiving JSON response

```
var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as! NSDictionary
```

But when not receiving actual json this line fail with error cannot cast value of NSArray to NSDictionary

I understand why this happen my question is how to properly check what format is the response

Comment: why not always return JSON ?

Comment: Server offline data unavaliable etc...

Comment: These are 2 very different things : the HTTP status is the thing you want to test for "server offline"; Wikipedia has a [list of http status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), but you'll probably be interested mainly by code 20. For data unavailibility, either you ensure to return a custom status code other than 200 (and then you decide whether you deal with it showing a nice error code or fail like "server down" case), either you always encapsulate your data into a "response" JSON object, itself containing a response code you can deal with in the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safe Dynamic JSON Casts In Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100138/safe-dynamic-json-casts-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I do like this in my api's:

```
typealias JSONType = (dictionary: [String:AnyObject]?, array: [AnyObject]?)

var error:NSError?
var json:AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error)
if let dict = json as? [String:AnyObject] {
    return (dict, nil) 
}
else if let arr = json as? [AnyObject] { 
    return (nil, arr)
}
```

So when I return that JSONType I can change to use it as a dictionary or array by just:

```
json.array
```